# How to get pgfonlayer to work correctly inside onslide?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am trying to use onslide to group different picture elements
together and control when and how long they appear on the slide.  At
the same time I am trying to use pgfonlayer to make sure some things
are drawn "underneath" other things to ensure the right occlusion.

I think they should be completely independent of each other, but I am
finding that when I put elements into the pgfonlayer environment
(which is inside the onslide), it seems to put all the items in the
same pgf background layer into something equivalent to onslide<1->.
Almost like the pgfonlayer cancels the effect of the onslide.

To be more precise I can have something like this (this is a sketch of
the problem -- A,B,C,D are real graphics, not just letters):

```
\onslide<1>{
B
\begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
A % A should be occluded by B
\end{pgfonlayer}
}

\onslide<2>{
D
\begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
C % C should be occluded by D
\end{pgfonlayer}
}
```

and I get the effect that A and C are always visible.

Is there an easy way to fix this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ambrose

ps.  Here is a full source code example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\title{onslide vs pgfonlayer}
\author[My Team]{My Name}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{First using pgfonlayer only -- works.}

  On this first slide the light colors are on top, even though they are
  drawn before the darker colors.  {\bf pgfonlayer} is used to achieve
  this.

  \pgfdeclarelayer{bg}
  \pgfsetlayers{bg,main}

  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[fill=blue!10] (0,1) circle (1cm);
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
        \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (1cm);
      \end{pgfonlayer}
      \draw[fill=red!10] (3,1) circle (1cm);
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
        \draw[fill=red] (3,0) circle (1cm);
      \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{Next, adding onslide -- fails.}
  On this second slide I attempt to use {\bf onslide} to show only one
  side at a time.  First the blues then the reds.
  \pgfdeclarelayer{bg}
  \pgfsetlayers{bg,main}

  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \onslide<1>{
        \draw[fill=blue!10] (0,1) circle (1cm);
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
          \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
      }
      \onslide<2>{
        \draw[fill=red!10] (3,1) circle (1cm);
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
          \draw[fill=red] (3,0) circle (1cm);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
      }

    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}

  First we see light blue with both dark colors, ...\pause and then we
  see light red with both dark colors.  It seems that because I put the
  darker colors into the bg layer, the onslide groupings I put around
  each basic color do not work

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses (both work nicely!).  Just hope there is a long term fix because having to specify the same information (the onslide argument) in two places makes source files slightly more difficult to maintain.  Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 6):

I think this is one of those instances that `beamer` and TikZ miscommunicate. The easiest solution is to add specific overlay specs to the `draw` commands on the `background` layer which makes the overlay specification become an `\only` (if I'm not mistaken). So, it's deliberately instructed to remove what happened on that slide unlike `\onslide`.

I would strongly recommend using the `backgrounds` library of TikZ which is tailored just for this task. I don't know exactly all the things it does but it's best to let TikZ do the layering if it's just the background that we are interested in.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\title{onslide vs pgfonlayer}
\author[My Team]{My Name}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{First using pgfonlayer only -- works.}

  On this first slide the light colors are on top, even though they are
  drawn before the darker colors.  \textbf{pgfonlayer} is used to achieve
  this.


  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[fill=blue!10] (0,1) circle (1cm);
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]  
    \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \end{scope}
      \draw[fill=red!10] (3,1) circle (1cm);
        \begin{scope}[on background layer] 
      \draw[fill=red] (3,0) circle (1cm);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[t]{Next, adding onslide -- fails.}
    On this second slide the light colors are on top, even though they are
  drawn before the darker colors.  \textbf{pgfonlayer} is used to achieve
  this.

  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \onslide<1>{
        \draw[fill=blue!10] (0,1) circle (1cm);
        \begin{scope}[on background layer] 
        \draw<1>[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \end{scope}
      }
      \onslide<2>{
        \draw[fill=red!10] (3,1) circle (1cm);
        \begin{scope}[on background layer] 
        \draw<2>[fill=red] (3,0) circle (1cm);
        \end{scope}
      }

    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}

  First \pause and second
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A small detail: `\bf` is depracated, use `\textbf` for such use.

Answer (score 6):

You are right: the `pgfonlayer` environment cancels the effect of the `\onslide`!

A workaround:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{pgfonlayer and onslide...}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{bg}
  \pgfsetlayers{bg,main}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \onslide<1>{
        \draw[fill=blue!10] (0,1) circle (1cm);
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
          \onslide<1>{
            \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (1cm);
          }
        \end{pgfonlayer}
      }
      \onslide<2>{
        \draw[fill=red!10] (3,1) circle (1cm);
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
          \onslide<2>{
            \draw[fill=red] (3,0) circle (1cm);
          }
        \end{pgfonlayer}
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]